# Expression Blend 3 TFS referesh problem

Tags: tfs, blend

When I checkout, checkin, rename soemthing in Vs 2008 SP1 while I have the project open in Expression Blend 3, these changes are not updated in Blend until I close and reopen the solution in blend or I try to checkout/checkin an item that is aready checked out. Is this a known bug? And is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a known bug. But there is a Menuitem "Refersh Source Control Status" in the context menu for the solution item in the project pane.